# How to create an own asynchronous function in a different file in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I want to write my own function for example:

own_function.js:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
 var js_object;
 // Do some stuff with above javascript object
 // After I want to attach "js_object" to request object:
 req.js = js_object;

 next();
 // also tried next(req, res);
}
```

I want to use this function in a different for example "main.js" file:

main.js:

```
var own_function = require(__dirname + '/own_function');

own_function(req, res, function(){

// Also tried own_function(req, res, function(req, res){

console.log(req.js_object);

});
```

It's not working I got undefined object. I think it's only syntax issue, but I don't know what is the correct syntax, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.js` you're calling `console.log(req.js_object);`, but in `own_function.js`, you're setting `req.js`, not `req.js_object`.  Those two things need to match.  I'd suggest changing `main.js`:

```
var own_function = require(__dirname + '/own_function');

own_function(req, res, function(){

    console.log(req.js); // was req.js_object

});
```

Comment: Haha, I already knew what you told me, but I screwed up in the example and also in my code LOL :). Anyway good catch thx the help:).

Comment: Happens to all of us :)